# Working with sequences odoo 9

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I'm working with sequences in Odoo 9 and I need some help with the default functions:

My actual model read the value from a field and then check in the sequences table if exists a sequence with that code (same as the label), if not exists, my custom create function create the sequence and assign a value for the sequence field.

Now my problem is when I unlink a record I want to let free again the spot on the sequence.

As a reference ill post my create function:

```
@api.model
def create(self,vals):
    prefix          =   "v"
    code            =   str(vals['label'])
    name            =   prefix+"_"+code
    implementation  =   "no_gap"
    dict            =   {"prefix":prefix,
                         "code":code,
                         "name":name,
                         "active":True,
                         "implementation":implementation
                        }

    if vals.get('sequence','New') == 'New':
        #First if will return True if can find a value for the field sequence in the current entry, if not, will return 'New'
        if self.env['ir.sequence'].search([('code','=',code)]).code == code:
            vals['sequence']    =   self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code(code)
            result  =   super(t_self_sequence,self).create(vals)
            return result
        else:
            new_seq = self.env['ir.sequence'].create(dict)
            vals['sequence']    =   self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code(code)
            result  =   super(t_self_sequence,self).create(vals)
            return result
```

I was trying to update the number_next valuein my unlink() function but can't figure out how to do it correctly, because if I just use a write on the sequence model i'll update the value but if as example I have 3 records:

Version/Label

V1 Hello

V2 Hello

V3 Hello

And then I delete the V2 Hello and write as number_next the 2 on my sequence, the following record will have V2 Hello but the number_next will be update to 3, so if I add another record ill have another V3 Hello and that will make my data inconsistent

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to reopen the spot in the sequence if a record is deleted? The only solution I can think of is to just iterate through the whole series and use the first one that's not found. Something like this?

```
# I'm not sure of your exact fields, so you'll want to adapt some of this
object = self.env['model.name']
i = 1
stop = False
while stop != True:
    label = 'V%d Hello' % i
    record = object.search([('name','=',label)])
    if record:
        i += 1
    else:
        stop = True

new_sequence = label
```

<sub><sup>Disclaimer: I  don't like this solution</sup></sub>